# Prevent scroll event propagation in mCustomScrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, event-propagation

I am using the [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) to create custom scrollers on div elements. When scrolling inside of a div and reaching the bottom end of the div, the page will start scrolling. Is there a way to prevent the scroll event from propagating?

I have created a http://jsfiddle.net/7CPv5/ to illustrate the issue. Just resize the browser to create a vertical scrollbar and start scrolling inside the "Hello World" div. I am calling the plugin like this:

```
$('#scrollable').mCustomScrollbar({
    scrollInertia: 0
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Different way to solve this:

```
$("#scrollable").mouseenter(function(){     

   $("#content-md").mCustomScrollbar("disable");  

}).mouseleave(function(){

   $("#content-md").mCustomScrollbar("update");

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but if someone stumbles upon it, here is the plugin-native way to do it without extra scripting:

```
$('#scrollable').mCustomScrollbar({
    scrollInertia: 0,
    mouseWheel: {preventDefault: true}
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/263

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
$('#scrollable').mCustomScrollbar({
    scrollInertia: 0
});

var customScrollerFocused = false,      
    UserScrollDisabler = function() {
    // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
    // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40
    this.scrollEventKeys = [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40];
    this.$window = $(window);
    this.$document = $(document);
};

UserScrollDisabler.prototype = {
    disable_scrolling_on_custom_scroll_focused : function() {
        var t = this;
        t.$window.on("mousewheel.UserScrollDisabler DOMMouseScroll.UserScrollDisabler", this._handleWheel);
        t.$document.on("mousewheel.UserScrollDisabler touchmove.UserScrollDisabler", this._handleWheel);
        t.$document.on("keydown.UserScrollDisabler", function(event) {
            t._handleKeydown.call(t, event);
        });
    },

    enable_scrolling : function() {
        var t = this;
        t.$window.off(".UserScrollDisabler");
        t.$document.off(".UserScrollDisabler");
    },

    _handleKeydown : function(event) {
        if(customScrollerFocused) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.scrollEventKeys.length; i++) {
                if (event.keyCode === this.scrollEventKeys[i]) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    },

    _handleWheel : function(event) {            
        if(customScrollerFocused) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }           
    }
};

var disabler = new UserScrollDisabler();
disabler.disable_scrolling_on_custom_scroll_focused();

$('#scrollable').find(".mCustomScrollBox").hover(
    function() {
       customScrollerFocused = true;
    },
    function() {
       customScrollerFocused = false;
    }
);
```

The idea here is to prevent body scroll event handling when the focus is on the jQuery custom content scroller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery-scrollLock](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/jquery-scrollLock):

```
$('#scrollable').scrollLock();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `mousewheel` and `DOMMouseScroll` events and call `preventDefault()` if the event originated from inside a scrollable region.

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.mCustomScrollbar').data('mouseWheel')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```